# Sum aggregate parts of a piecwise function [SymPy]

Tags: sum, sympy, piecewise

Here is a self-contained script.

```py
from sympy import *

x = Symbol('x', real=True)
A = Symbol('A', real=True, positive=True, constant=True)
a = Symbol('a', real=True, positive=True, constant=True)
b = Symbol('b', real=True, positive=True, constant=True)

# Define wavefunction
psi_x_0 = Piecewise(
    (0, x < 0),
    (A * x / a, x <= a),
    (A * (b - x) / (b - a), x <= b),
    (0, True)
    )

# Square Norm
square_norm = integrate(psi_x_0**2, (x, a, b))
```

Is there a way to get a sum of the branches of `square_norm`? I have tried applying `Sum` and `sum` to it, but these give errors. I want to ignore the branch conditions, which is not really the intended use case I realize.

Comment: I'll trust that you know what you're doing but I'm having a hard time picturing a sound reason for the operations shown in this code e.g. what does `t` have to do with anything?

Comment: @OscarBenjamin This is a toy problem from quantum mechanics. The wave function in this problem is set to time `t=0` implicitly, which is why it isn't obvious from the code. There's a normalization criterion that I check, but it isn't necessary for this SO post. I'll delete these aspects.

Answer (score 1):

A simple list comprehension should do the trick:

```py
# arg is a tuple of 2-elements tuple:
# ((expr1, cond1), (expr2, cond2), ...)
# let's sum expr1, expr2
sum([a[0] for a in square_norm.args])
```

Comment: While this will work and is fine in this case it is generally better (more efficient) to use `Add(*expressions)` rather than `sum(expressions)`.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin I checked the run times in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/dde37f147b14c97093d03b74589dda88) for using `Add` vs `sum` and found that the `Add` approach is about 5.7 times faster on my system. Please post using `Add(*expressions)` as an answer so I can give you credit for providing a useful answer.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin please write an answer and also explain why it is faster,

Comment: I don't need credit. That `Add` point would be better as an answer to a different question. Using `sum(*expressions)` is quadratic (`O(n^2)`) rather than linear. For a big list of expressions there will be a noticeable difference but here there are only two expressions so it doesn't matter.